# Showing label in custom validator

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I created a new custom component implementing a custom validator.
Here is how I call it in:

```
<p:inputText value="#{MyBean.value}" >
    <f:attribute name="label" value="#{ResourceBean.labels['label']}"/>

    <my:validator error="#{ResourceBean.message['the.error.message']}" 
                  expression="#{ResourceBean.regExp['alphanumeric']}"/>
</p:inputText>
```

And here is the validate implementation

```
String val = value == null ? "" : value.toString();

if (!val.matches(getExpression())) {
    throw new ValidatorException(new 
              FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,getErrorSummary(),null));
```

and the error message in property file:

```
the.error.message={0}\: is Invalid.
```

The problem is that the `{0}` in not replaced by the label in the error message thus I am getting as error message:

```
{0}: is Invalid.
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`MessageFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) API, like as JSF is doing under the covers.

```
String message = getErrorSummary();
String label = component.getAttributes().get("label");
String formattedMessage = MessageFormat.format(message, label);
throw new ValidatorException(new FacesException(formattedMessage));
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you expecting a different behavior?  In the code posted I don't see where you are explicitly doing a token replace on the `{0}` substring of your error message.

I usually do something like the following:

```
String messageBody = stringBuffer.toString().replaceAll("\\{0\\}", firstName);
```

Or your string can utilize proper syntax for string token replacement for use in String's format method:

```
String.format("%s: is Invalid.", "token");
```